# Web Security is authenticated always return "false"

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-mvc-4, webmatrix

i have a issue with my websecurity authentication , i can't login is. authenticated retrurn always false 
 When I login always it sends me to login page. I debugged it and I found a problem httpContext.Request.IsAuthenticated always return false , any help ..
Controller :

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
        {
            ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
            return View();
        }
        [AllowAnonymous]
        [HttpPost]
        public ActionResult Login(UserProfile register)
        {

            WebSecurity.Login(register.UserName, register.password, true);
            if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
            {
                return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
            }

            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Contact");
        }
```

view :

```
<h2>@ViewBag.Title.</h2>
<div class="row">
    <div class="col-md-8">
        <section id="loginForm">
            @using (Html.BeginForm("Login", "AccountHopital", new { ReturnUrl = ViewBag.ReturnUrl }, FormMethod.Post, new { @class = "form-horizontal", role = "form" }))
            {
                @Html.AntiForgeryToken()
                <h4>Utilisez un compte local pour vous connecter.</h4>
                <hr />
                @Html.ValidationSummary(true, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.TextBoxFor(m => m.UserName, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.UserName, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
                <div class="form-group">
                    @Html.LabelFor(m => m.password, new { @class = "col-md-2 control-label" })
                    <div class="col-md-10">
                        @Html.PasswordFor(m => m.password, new { @class = "form-control" })
                        @Html.ValidationMessageFor(m => m.password, "", new { @class = "text-danger" })
                    </div>
                </div>
```

and web.config :

```
  <system.web>
    <membership defaultProvider="SimpleMembershipProvider">
      <providers>
        <add name="SimpleMembershipProvider" type="WebMatrix.WebData.SimpleMembershipProvider, WebMatrix.WebData"  />
      </providers>

    </membership>

    <authentication mode="Forms">
      <!--<modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
</modules>-->
      <forms  loginUrl="~/AccountHopital/Login" timeout="3600" />

    </authentication>
    <compilation debug="true" targetFramework="4.5" />
    <httpRuntime targetFramework="4.5" />
  </system.web>
  <system.webServer>
    <modules>
      <remove name="FormsAuthentication" />
    </modules>
  </system.webServer>
```

Answer (score 1):

`User.Identity.IsAuthenticated` looks at the authentication cookie from the client to determine if the user is logged in or not.  Since the authentication cookie is not present when you are POSTing to your login method, it will always return false.  Additionally, why perform the check right after you logged the user in?  The check should actually be performed on the login GET method.

```
public ActionResult Login(string returnUrl)
    {
       if (User.Identity.IsAuthenticated)
        {
            //already logged in - no need to allow login again!!
            return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
        }
        ViewBag.ReturnUrl = returnUrl;
        return View();
    }

    [AllowAnonymous]
    [HttpPost]
    public ActionResult Login(UserProfile register)
    {
        //check your model state!
        if(!ModelState.IsValid) return View();

        //this method returns some result letting you know if the user 
        //logged in successfully or not.  You need to check that. 

        //Additionally, this method sets the Auth cookie so you can 
        //do you IsAuthenticated call anywhere else in the system 
        var loginResult = WebSecurity.Login(register.UserName, register.password, true);

        //login failed, display the login view again or go whereever you need to go
        if(!loginResult) return View();

         //Good to go, user is authenticated - redirect to where need to go
        return RedirectToAction("Index", "Home");
    }
```

[Here is the MSDN](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/webmatrix.webdata.websecurity.login(v=vs.111).aspx) for the WebSecurity.Login method

Comment: it's always false : HasUserID= false , Isauthenticated= false :/

Comment: If you are checking inside of the POST login method, it will be.  You have to redirect to another action in order for the cookie et. al. to be avaialble.  Try to 1) Login and 2) go back to login page using the code above.  Again, you have to have a successful call to your `WebSecurity.Login` method **AND** you have to redirect to another request for the cookie to be applied.

Comment: i try to use formsauthentication.setauthcookie and it's ok , it's the problem of cookie in WebSecurity.Login .